# Numeric variable to character variable conversion

Tags: formatting, sas

I'm trying to plot two sets of calculations and compare them over time. The "cohort" variable, derived from coh_asof_yyyymm from original table, were stored in the data set in numeric format (201003 for 2010 March). Now when I plot them by using proc sgplot, 4 quarters of data are crammed together. How do I change the format of this variable in order to product outputs where x-axis should be in interval of quarters?

```
options nofmterr;
libname backtest "/retail/mortgage/consumer/new"; 

proc sql;
create table frst_cur as
select
coh_asof_yyyymm as cohort,
sum(annual_default_occurrence* wt)/sum(wt) as dr_ct,
sum(ScorePIT_PD_2013 * wt)/sum(wt) as pd_ct_pit,
sum(ScoreTTC_PD_2013 * wt)/sum(wt) as pd_ct_ttc
from backtest.sample_frst_cur_201312bkts
group by 1;
quit;

proc sgplot data = frst_cur;
    series x = cohort y = pd_ct_pit;
    series x = cohort y = pd_ct_ttc;
    format cohort yyyyqc.;
    xaxis label = 'Cohort Date';
    yaxis label = 'Defaults';
    title 'First Mortgage Current';
run;
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to suggest a solution without seeing some of the data and the output.  Can you upload the output and add in a few records from the FRST_CUR table?

Comment: I'm unable to upload the graph produced by the code, but the first 5 lines of output data looks something like this:

Comment: cohort           dr_ct              pd_ct_pit          pd_ct_ttc

Comment: 200003            0.0056         0.0087           0.0094

Comment: 200006  0.0053 0.0079 0.0093

Comment: 200009 0.0048 0.0077 0.0092

Comment: 200012 0.0043 0.0076 0.0093

Comment: The first column is the four digit year followed by two digits of month. This pattern of 4 repeats itself until 201312, with the respective dr, pit, and ttc percentages. The graph produced have clusters of four dots together because of its numeric format. The SAS system reads in numerical numbers of 200,003 to 200,009 so the difference between those four are very minimal, rather than even amount of space between each unit of a quarter year. I hope I've made this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm getting it right, i think your date is a number and not a SAS date. It's not unusual, people do store date as integers in their RDBMS tables and when SAS import data from table, it assumes it to be integer rather than date. Check out the below solution code for reference.

```
data testing_date_integer;
infile datalines missover;
input int_date 8.;
      /* creating another variable which would be a SAS date, based on int_date.
         we would be converting the integer date to charater and then append 
         day (01) to the charater and read using YYMMDD8. informat for SAS 
         to store the character as date
      */
      sas_date=input(cats(put(int_date,8.),'01'),yymmdd8.);

format sas_date YYQ8.;
datalines4;
200008
200009
200010
200011
200012
200101
200102
200103
200104
200105
200106
;;;;
run;
proc print data=testing_date_integer;run;
```

If above code show and solves you problem then i would recommend you to update you PROC SQL Code

```
proc sql;
create table frst_cur as
select
input(cats(put(coh_asof_yyyymm ,8.),'01'),yymmdd8.) as cohort,
.
.
.
```

Also, i would recommend updating the format statement for cohort in PROC SGPLOT

```
proc sgplot data = frst_cur;
.
.
    format cohort yyq8.;
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [YYMMn6. informat](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000363557.htm)

```
data HAVE;
input DATE YYMMn6.;
format date YYQ8.;
datalines;
200008
200009
200010
200011
200012
200101
200102
200103
200104
200105
200106
;
run;
Proc Print Data=HAVE noobs; Run;

data HAVE2;
input coh_asof_yyyymm 8.;
datalines;
200008
200009
200010
200011
200012
200101
200102
200103
200104
200105
200106
;
run;

proc sql;
create table frst_cur as
select
 input(put(coh_asof_yyyymm,6.),YYMMn6.) as cohort format=YYQ8.
From HAVE2;
Quit;
```